# google chart vertical text not showing in JQuery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, user-interface, charts

I am using Google Chart API to display a graph. If I display the graph in a DIV on a page it works fine. However, when I display the exact same graph in a DIV in a Dialog Box created using JQuery UI, the vertical text does not display. Everything else is fine, just the vertical text is missing from the graph in the UI Dialog Box.

I have tried overriding with "vAxis:{textPosition:'out'}" which is the default with no luck.

Comment: I finally found that by opening the dialog box and then drawing the graph, the vertical text displayed correctly. I can't see why this would affect only the vertical text, but is seems that it does.